# How to keep the table layout while exporting PDF file from Word document using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, office-interop

I am trying to export Word document that contains table to PDF format, the exporting is done successfully but the layout of the table after exporting is not the same as it was before.

How to keep the table layout while exporting PDF file from Word document ?

Before Exporting (Word Format):-

[image]

After Exporting (PDF Format):-

[image]

The Code that I used:-

```
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(targetDocPathPDF, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, false, WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen,
                     WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 1, 1, WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, true, true,
                     WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, true, true, false, ref oMissing);
```

Or

```
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(targetDocPathPDF, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat wdSaveFmt = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
object oWdSaveFmt = wdSaveFmt, oSaveAsSpec = targetDocPathPDF;
doc.SaveAs2(ref oSaveAsSpec, ref oWdSaveFmt);
```

Comment: What do you mean by… _” table to PDF format”_ ? Is there a PDF document in the Word document? I would assume that the table is a WORD table? This is unclear. Can you supply a Word document that reproduces this? Otherwise, speculation is all you may get.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and solved it by setting the column width's to be about 10% smaller. It threw off the formatting in the Word document but the PDF is coming out correctly.